# Digital Root exercise on Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble trying to do a digital root exercise on Javascript.

Here's my code:

```
function digital_root(n) {
    var sNumero = n.toString();
    var sum = 0;

    for(i = 0 ; i < sNumero.length; i++){
        sum += parseInt(sNumero[i]);
    }

    if(sum > 9){
        digital_root(sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

When I try to input 456 to 'n', the function gives 15 as the return. The expected is 6. I don't know why this is happening.

To help you guys understand my problem, here's the exercise:

"A digital root is the recursive sum of all the digits in a number. Given n, 
 take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has more than one digit, 
 continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is produced. This is 
 only applicable to the natural numbers."

Comment: No ((4 + 5) = 9) + 6 = 15

Comment: @LawrenceCherone 15 => 1 + 5 = 6

Comment: @alfasin eek, I missed the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a return:

```
if(sum > 9){
    return digital_root(sum); // <-- here
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help. I'm starting in this world, so I'm having some trouble on basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `return` statement here on

```js
function digital_root(n) {

  var sNumero = n.toString();
  var sum = 0;


  for (i = 0; i < sNumero.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(sNumero[i]);
  }

  if (sum > 9) {
    return digital_root(sum); // missing return here
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(digital_root(456))
```

**OR** add a new **variable** to capture the final result before returning.

```js
function digital_root(n) {

  var sNumero = n.toString();
  var sum = 0;
  var final_result; // introduce new variable to hold recursive sum

  for (i = 0; i < sNumero.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(sNumero[i]);
  }

  final_result = sum; // assign sum to final_result variable
  if (sum > 9) {
    final_result = digital_root(sum);
  }

  return final_result; // return final_result
}

console.log(digital_root(456))
```

Comment: I forgot that i have to somehow get the value back. I think that the first example is the best solution